# How to set <div> height without leaks?

Tags: html, css

I'm desiging my page as:
Fixed top and side menus, main page scrollable depending on contents, everything inside a container.
I can't figure out how to stop the container from leaking the  background in the bottom. I have tryed min-height: 100%, height: calc(100vh-50px), but none of this will work.
What I have so far

You can see the background leak in https://jsfiddle.net/0afeh6cb/

How can I get rid of that?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

#topMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  width: 980px;
  height: 40px;
}

#sideMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ------------- Container ------------- */

#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 790px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f0ffff;
}

#footer {
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 790px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topMenu">
    <p>Top Menu</p>
  </div>

  <div id="sideMenu">
    <h3>Side menu</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <h1>My content here</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-y: auto;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
body,
#container {
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  /*height: calc(100vh - 50px);*/ You can remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the fixed positioning from your `#topMenu`.

   ```
   #topMenu {
     // position: fixed; <-- removed
     // top: 0px; <-- removed
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     background-color: #e0e0e0;
     width: 980px;
     height: 40px;
   }
   ```
2. Remove the positioning from your `#container` and your calculated height and set a `height` of `100vh` to prevent background bleeding entirely.

   ```
   #container {
     height: 100vh; // <-- added
     background-color: #fff;
     // position: relative; <-- removed
     width: 1000px;
     // min-height: calc(100vh - 50px); <-- removed
     margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
   }
   ```
3. Remove the margin top from your #main container.

   ```
   #main {
     // margin-top: 50px; <-- removed
     margin-left: 190px;
     width: 790px;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #f0ffff;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the container class css as below:

> 100vh always take the total height of its parent div.

```
#container {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    _min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);//remove this line
    height: 100vh; //Set this height.
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
```